# Nodejs: Post method url body parser shows undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, body-parser

I want to use url post params to execute mysql query. I am getting error during mysql command when I post through postman. I dont know what is problem with this code. Here is my code

```
var express    = require('express');   
var app        = express();               
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var md5 = require('MD5');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "shoaib",
  password: "",
  database: "watch"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;        
var router = express.Router();  

router.post('/',function(req, res) {

  con.connect(function(err) {
    var query = "Select * From user Where email=? AND password=?";
     var table = [req.body.email,req.body.password ];
     console.log(req.body);

        query = mysql.format(query, table);
        con.query(query, function (err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({ "Error": true, "Message": "Error executing MySQL query" });
            } else if(rows!=0) {
                res.json({ "Error": false, "Message": "Success","Users": rows });
            } else {
                res.json({ "Error": true,});
            }
        });
    });
  });

app.use('/api', router);
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Node is working perfectly but when I execute command url I face error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure on your request that you set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` since your app supports either. Without a `Content-Type` header with either of these values `body-parser` will not read the request body and `res.body` will be `undefined`.

#### Example POST Request with `Content-Type: application/json`

```
const {request} = require('http')

const requestBody = {email: 'abc@gmail.com', password: 'abcdef123456'}

const jsonPostRequest = request({
  method: 'POST',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 8080,
  path: '/api/',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
}, res => {
  let chunks = ''
  // Handle Response Chunk
  res.on('data', chunk => (chunks += chunk))

  // Handle Response Ended, print response body
  res.on('end', () => console.log(chunks))
})

jsonPostRequest.write(requestBody)
jsonPostRequest.end()
```